# Class field type based on class state

Tags: typescript

Given these classes:

```
class A {
    foo = 'Hello, World!';
}

class B {
    initialized: boolean = false;
    bar: A | null = null;
    
    initialize(): void {
        this.bar = new A();
        this.initialized = true;
    }
}
```

Assume that `B.initialize` is supposed to be called after the constructor. If I wanted to access `B.bar.foo` (Assuming `B.bar` is an instance of `A`), I personally would do it either of these ways:

```
const b = new B();
b.initialize();
console.log(b.bar!.foo);
console.log((b.bar as A).foo);
```

However, because `B.bar` will always be *not* `null` after calling `initialize`, I'm wondering if there is a way for `B.bar`'s type to just be `A`, instead of staying a union of `A | null`. Essentially, I want the type of `B.bar` to depend on the value of `B.initialized`.

I've tried something like this:

```
class B {
    initialized: boolean = false;
    bar: this['initialized'] extends true ? A : null = null;
    // My thinking is: if this.initialized === true, then type is A; else null
}
```

However that doesn't work because the type of `initialized` is always `boolean` and never `true` or `false`. So, I'm curious, is something like this possible? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, your desired behavior is the default: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1oEsB2aAuawjQC8BTAEwC5oAjAexpGLA2gF5oAzfCYgbhQ7oB+ShGwAnTAHM+-TDjwESACgCUlAG400pRP1TYAFmggA6dnVbQARAAliIEDQA00AOo0xIUgEIrfVPpGpnK4+ERkluIArrz8AL5ICUjANBii0GCWGMQA7nCqfClp9MQmjpJK2ACeAA7ENOwZZnQqfGAmIQrhBcmpECVlNBXVdQ1N5jStSEA

Comment: @Julia My question is concerned with compile time. When you hover over `a.foo` to see its compile time type, it is `string | undefined`. I was looking for some way to just be `undefined` before the call to `initialize`, and `string` after the call, so no casting or explicit type narrowing is required if I wanted to access `foo`'s properties.

Comment: Ah, I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a nice way to achieve what you are looking for. My personal recommendation is to use a getter function instead of trying to access `foo` directly.

I'm also a fan of writing out the states in a way which makes it so that impossible states are unrepresentable. In this case, it should be impossible for `initialized` to be `false` and for `foo` to be a string (or the opposite, for `initialized` to be true, and for `foo` to be undefined).

The class state can be represented as a union type to avoid invalid states. This would look like:

```
type State = { initialized: true; foo: string } | { initialized: false }
```

An example which follows these two suggestions may look like so:

```
class A {
  // we can make this state private as we don't want to expose it outside
  // of our class
  private state: 
    | { initialized: true, foo: string }
    | { initialized: false } = { initialized: false } 
  
  initialize(): void {
    this.state = { foo: "Hello, World!", initialized: true };
  }

  // This function will throw an error if this class is used incorrectly
  getFoo(): string {
    if (this.state.initialized === false) {
      throw new Error("A.initialize must be called before trying to access foo")
    }

    return this.state.foo
  }
}

const a = new A()
a.initialize();
const foo = a.getFoo();
```